# Simulating how an app would look on various Projectors

Tags: web-app, screen-resolution, contrast

I've done a few google searches and not coming up with anything useful:

I was wondering if anyone knew of any software or techniques that you could use to simulate how a web application would look on various projectors?

We are trying to address concerns that the software doesn't project well for demos.

I am thinking of something like https://michelf.ca/projects/sim-daltonism/ where you can hang it over the app and get a view how it might look.

Except of course it might both shrink the resolution and reduce number of colors? Or maybe there is a commonly known way to reduce resolution and colors that approximates?

Comment: The same way you test how something looks on different browsers, tablets and on different operating systems - test using those actual devices. There are test labs out there that can provide access to such devices, or just buy some if your project depends on the output working on such systems.

Comment: @JonW is right. This would be nearly impossible to simulate because you do not have a single point of diminished display capabilities. The projector output is going to vary based on input such as VGA vs HDMI, bulb manufacturer, the age of the bulb, the lens, and last but not least the processing capabilities of the projector. Besides, this question is not on-track for this site.

Comment: To add to this, just like you need to know what browsers the majority of users will use on for a web app. You also need to know what's a typical type of projectors you'll likely be demoing from. Not a bad idea to have a "worse case scenario" test and a "decent projector" test. Keep in mind if they have a crappy projector, everybody knows it's a crappy projector and will adjust their expectations based on that.

Comment: OK, was just an idea i can test real devices was looking for something that would give me a cursory test and view where i can say look how it looks, take a screen shot ect...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about solving a non-UX problem.

Comment: There are UX guidelines for making presentations that will display on a projector and making TV applications that will display and work properly on smart televisions. That being said, it would be difficult to make a tool that could simulate all those different use cases. If you could be more specific about your use cases, may be we could still help you. Under what circumstances will your demo be shown? Lighting? Demo booth/keynote? in store? Is the UI centered on the screen to mitigate overscan? Does it need to be interactive or just viewable? How far from the screen will the audience be?

Comment: I think in my case the number one issue will be color hues that don't show up on projectors. For example the hover,selection colors ect are out of the normal spectrum of projectors. So maybe its about the correct range of colors to be using and if that can be tested? Its my theory but i'm not sure that we support WCAG AA or AAA for at least one projectable theme it would help. http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/

Answer (score 1):

If you have detailed information on the projectors colour profiles, you could do a rough simulation by **setting your monitor's colour profile to match that of the projector**.  It's never going to give you an exact representation, but the only way to really get that is to test it on the projector you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

For developing Television applications, the number one mistakes developers make is to confuse their computer screens with actual television screens.

So having a web based simulator would only exacerbate this problem, because developers would only be using their computer and existing computer screens to browse the site from.

For a television, one should assume that the audience will be sitting/standing at least 10 feet away from the television itself (at least, that's according to the Google TV guidelines). This will make your font actually look gigantic and feel wrong when you're sitting just in front your computer screen, but this guideline is absolutely crucial. You must try using some of the same distances and some of the same projectors that your audience will be using when viewing your product, whether those distances be 10 ft, 20 ft, or 50 ft.

For a projector, I'm not sure if that 10 ft distance guideline really applies, but for preparing slides for a projector, the recommended aspect ratio is usually 16/9. Unfortunately, that aspect/ratio is only a rough estimate (if you don't know which projector you'll be using).